# cancelAllLocalNotifications in applicationWillTerminate?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to cancelAllLocalNotifications and setApplicationIconBadgeNumber to 0 when my application is terminated (either by the OS or by double tapping the home button and killing the app). I simply added these two calls to my primary app delegate code:

```
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application 
{
        [application cancelAllLocalNotifications];
        [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
}
```

Existing notifications are still running and the badge number remains set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applicationWillTerminate:` is not called by the OS when it kills your app. The OS just kills the process without notifying your app about it. There is no documented way to execute code at this moment.

Comment: what about when the user terminates the app by double tap on the home button and hit the minus sign?

Comment: It's the same thing - easily checked with the debugger

Comment: Thanks. I can now stop looking :-)

Comment: so are you saying that executing code when the app is about to be terminated is not possible?

Comment: That's right, you can't execute code at termination. Best you can do is update your state in case it gets terminated when app resigns active or app goes into the background.

Comment: Sucks - even tried installing signal handlers for SIGKILL... Have gotten them to fire a couple times in the simulator, but it's not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [applicationWillResignActive:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a) instead.

Starting with iOS 4.0 applicationWillTerminate is not called for applications when they are killed in the background.  Apps are put in the background when you hit the home button now or otherwise switch apps.

Comment: Unfortunately this will mean that the local notifications are removed every time the app is sent to the background, which I'm not sure is the required result.