# Removing Local Notifications when app has been terminated

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilocalnotification, application-lifecycle

In my app, I set up local notifications to notify the user while the app is running. In order to clean these up in case the app is terminated, I have set up `applicationWillTerminate:` to clear these notifications:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

Unfortunately, if the app crashes, or I terminate debugging, this function isn't called and therefore I still get the local notifications delivered to the device.

Is there a way of definitely checking if the application has quit unexpectedly so I can tidy these up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this **KSCrash** library with great success. Maybe it can help you also:

```
https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash
```

Or alternatively, have you set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` on your .plist file? If you don't, there is no guarantee that `applicationWillTerminate` will be called, when using iOS 4.

Comment: It looks like a good crash reporter, but unfortunately it only allows a call to a C method on crash, not Objective-C, and therefore I won't be able to call `cancelAllLocalNotifications`.

Comment: OK. I'll see if I can find another solution. Thanks for your message.

Comment: Based on your idea, I tried Crittercism, which has an Objective-C delegate for when it crashes... Unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Comment: I was thinking about Crittercism also. I've updated my answer and maybe that can help you somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` either, because my app needs to work in the background. The local notifications I set are supposed to remind you in the background, however if the app crashes or is unloaded, I need for the local notifications to be removed.

Comment: I've altered the name of my question so it's a bit more apparent what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: I have also found that this is a possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398191/cancelalllocalnotifications-in-applicationwillterminate - I'll let the moderators decide what to do with this question :)

Comment: Yes, it seems like a duplicate. Any progress so far?

Comment: Not really. I considered removing them on memory warning, but this probably won't get fired if the OS decides to quit the app while it is in the background. I also considered only firing off local notifications instantly when needed (I can do this because the app runs location services in the background), but I fear it would require a lot of reprogramming!

Comment: As a note: whenever your app crashes you may only run async safe code, which by default excludes to run any Objective-C code. See http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html